# Automator to Applescript for Editing Code

Tags: applescript, increment, automator

Just wondering if I can convert a "watch me do" event in Automator to applescript and then edit the resulting code?  I've got a recording of entering a query (i.e. Apple1) into Google, but I'd like the query to increase ++ for each loop of the recording, so the result is Apple1, then the next loop would be Apple2, Apple3, etc.  I know increments are elementary in programming, but I'm just not sure how to do it using Automator and/or applescript.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can run AppleScript in Automator, but you can't edit an Automator action in AppleScript (unless that action was originally written in AppleScript and hasn't been saved as a compiled programme).

Comment: Actually you can. After you run a "watch me do." you can select all the commands and paste them into a Applescript Doc. But in my opinion it is a waste of time in most cases because the code is normal GUI commands. I.e click this or that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may be simpler just doing it all in Applescript.

Example:

```
   set counter to 0
set theTerm to "apple"
repeat 4 times
    set counter to counter + 1
    open location "http://www.google.co.uk/#hl=en&output=search&sclient=psy-ab&q=" & theTerm & counter
end repeat
```

Running this code will have your browser open a new search for apple1 through 4

**Update: Response to Comment request**:

This example shows you how to search google images and randomise the search using different terms and numbers.

```
set theTerms to {"apple", "orange", "banana", "pear"}
set termCount to count of theTerms

set searchLoc to "http://images.google.com/search?hl=en&site=&tbm=isch&source=hp&biw=2171&bih=1062&q="

repeat 4 times
    set termRandNumber to random number from 1 to termCount
    set randomSuffixNumber to random number from 1 to 7000
    open location searchLoc & item termRandNumber of theTerms & randomSuffixNumber
end repeat
```

Comment: wow that's brilliant and works perfectly.  the only problem is that i've tried changing the address "http://www.google.co.uk" to "http://www.images.google.com" but it seems to want to load the former anyway.  any idea how to get it to open the images section?  thanks again amazingly helpful

Comment: also, not to push it, but any way to randomize the prefix and number suffix?  in other words, scroll through a variety of words, such as apple, orange, banana and choose one and pair it with a randomly generated number such as 0013, 6593, 45, 2, etc. etc.  thanks again and sorry to ask so much

Answer (score 8):

A few years late but yes you can.

### How to convert a list of Watch Me Do events to AppleScript:

**1.** Record the Watch Me Do actions

**2.** In the Watch Me Do window select all of the events you want to edit

**3.** Drag those events to a blank position below the Watch Me Do window (*where you would place another Automator action*)

**4.** Edit!

--------------------------------------------------**See Below for Images**--------------------------------------------------

NOTE: *In Step 3, when dragging the actions to a blank space you will see a green circle icon with a white plus. Sorry I can't find the exact icon but here is one that looks close enough to give you the idea.*

[image: Green Circle Plus Icon]

---

### STEP 1

[image: Step 1]

### STEP 2

[image: Step 2]

### STEP 3

[image: Step 3]

### STEP 4

[image: Step 4]

Comment: There are many places on the web that says this can't be done. And yet, here it is. Thank you!